# In Protractor e2e tests, how can I take a screenshot?

Tags: continuous-integration, protractor, screenshot

Running protractor, I want to call for a screenshot as part of my spec. 
I don't want to take a screenshot every test, and these "reporters" are taking them at every test, every failed test, or once per spec. 
This is all very meta, but more importantly I just want a picture to take, and save on a Bamboo CI server. 
Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made an npm module for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-protractor

Add the module to your project with:

```
npm install screenshot-protractor --save
```

In your conf.js file locate or create your onPrepare function.

```
onPrepare: function() {

}
```

inside your onPrepare, add this line:

```
global.screenshot = require('screenshot-protractor').saveScreenshot;
```

then in the spec.js file, add

```
screenshot('path/to/screenshots.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`takeScreenshot()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.takeScreenshot) and `fs` module:

```
var fs = require('fs');

browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (data) {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('test-results/test.png');

    stream.write(new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
    stream.end();
});
```